# Set apart items of UL and wrap them into another tags

Tags: jquery

I have a list such this:

```
<ul class='as-selections'>
    <li class='as-selection-item'> item1 </li>
    <li class='as-selection-item'> item2 </li>
    <li class='as-selection-item'> item3 </li>
    <li class='as-orjinal'> item3 </li>
</ul>
```

How can I group all items with `as-selection-item` class and wrap them in `<li class="thelist"><ul></ul></li>` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) :

```
$('.as-selection-item').wrapAll('<li><ul></ul></li>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3d24P/)

If you have more than one list, you'll have to iterate:

```
$('.as-selections').each(function(i, ul) {
    $('.as-selection-item', ul).wrapAll('<li><ul></ul></li>');
});
```